# I'm unable to parse image from the json which i get from the service to the recycler view

Tags: java, android, json

This is my Adapter class. I'm unable to parse image from the json which i get from the service.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
ImageView imgPost;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){
    super();

    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);
    holder.NameTextView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());
    holder.SubjectTextView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getSubject());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView NameTextView;
    public TextView SubjectTextView;
    ImageView imgPost;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        NameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostTitle) ;

        SubjectTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostDate) ;
        imgPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my model class.

**GetDataAdapter.class**

```
public class GetDataAdapter {

    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String subject;

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
}
```

This is my MainActivity class.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

ProgressBar progressBar;
String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";

String JSON_NAME =  "title";
String JSON_SUBJECT = "releaseYear";
String JSON_IMAGE = "image";

Button button;

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
RequestQueue requestQueue ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button) ;
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
        }
    });
}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            GetDataAdapter2.setname(json.getString(JSON_NAME));
            GetDataAdapter2.setSubject(json.getString(JSON_SUBJECT));
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Why unable? What errors do you get? Please be specific with the problem you have.

Comment: i dont have any error but the image doesn't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added any code in your RecyclerViewAdapter.class to load images from url. Try the steps below:

1) First check if you have added internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

2) I recommend using Picasso Library by Square to load images from url. Check
    it out here

http://square.github.io/picasso/

3) Add this dependency to your app gradle

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

4) Add the below line to your onBindViewHolder method inside your RecyclerViewAdapter.class

Picasso.with(context).load(getDataAdapter1.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imgPost);

Answer (score 1):

Volley network image view is useful when loading image from URL.
its just along with volley  library ,we dont need extra library for json parsing etc,

Picasso ,Glide, are also good libs for loading image from URL