# Android load image to RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an Android application and i use `Volley` to parse the text but the image is unable to parse and my question is:

**How to parse image from URL to ImageView in RecyclerView  using Json and Volley ?**

Comment: use http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Have you tried reading some tutorials or blogs yet?

Comment: thank you and this is my code how can i add this ???http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108249/im-unable-to-parse-image-from-the-json-which-i-get-from-the-service-to-the-recy?noredirect=1#comment65564207_39108249

Comment: please checkout this page : [volley/request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) and `NetworkImageView`  will help you in that page. Also you can use `Glide`, `Picasso` etc.

Comment: yes i try but always  i have same problem the image not display

Comment: Can you post your relevant code here, i can't see what you have so far

Comment: this is my code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108249/im-unable-to-parse-image-from-the-json-which-i-get-from-the-service-to-the-recy?noredirect=1#comment65564207_39108249)

Comment: I can't see your ImageView code in adapter class at onBindViewHolder. So what you have so far ?

Comment: yes because i dont know how to add image view onbindViewholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try using Picasso Library by Square to load images from url. Check
it out here

http://square.github.io/picasso/

2) Add this dependency to your app gradle

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

3) Add the below line to your onBindViewHolder method inside your RecyclerView adapter

Picasso.with(context).load(<your Image Url>).into(holder.<ImageView reference>);

Comment: this is for one image but i have a this Json URL  [link](http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json) and i have many image not one how to do it ?

Comment: just doing Picasso.with(context).load(<your Image Url>).into(holder.<ImageView reference>); once inside your onBindViewHolder method is sufficient